# Inapp billing subscription error Your order was declined because it was considered high-risk

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have implemented subscription with android inapp billing, and used Trivial Drive example for it as is (util package)

With "inapp" items all fine, I can buy this type's item, but if I try to buy subscription (type = "subs"), I get the strange error from google: **Your order was declined because it was considered high-risk**

In the google wallet of buyer's account is:

> Status Canceled Your purchase has been canceled. You won't be charged.
>   Oct 25 »   Google has canceled this purchase. Comments from Google:
>   Your order was declined because it was considered high-risk. Please
>   try again in 30 minutes.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a message from a fraud detection system Google uses to prevent malicious payment transactions from been executed. Before executing a payment transaction, Google tried to analyze how safe this transaction is. Multiple parameters can impact this check. A probability of "bad transaction" rises, for instance, when multiple payments are executed by different devices using the same credit card very often, or when same credit card is used by multiple accounts, or when user pays and then cancels payments multiple times in a row, etc.

This is a temporal error, which can disappear next day. Is you have no time to wait with testing, contact Google Play support and explain the situation. They will fix this issue for your development account. This is how I've got it solved.

Comment: You was right. I have tried do subscription with another account and it was done successful. Thanks!